# Weird path changes and forgotten file associations

Tags: android, xamarin.android, file-handling, intentfilter

I want my app to export data to the downloads directory.

To get the downloads directory, I use this code
`string path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath;`

The `path` variable has the value `"/storage/emulated/0/Download"`.

When I save my file to `Path.Combine(path, "myfile.ext")`, the file is being saved correctly.

To open that file with my app, I created an Activity `ImportActivity` with an attached `intent-filter`.

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern="/.*\\.ext" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:scheme="content" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Now, when I use the file browser (the one from Samsung) and navigate to the downloads directory, I can see my file.
After tapping on said file, my `ImportActivity` is being created and I get the file path `"/device_storage/Download/myfile.ext"` (same file in a different directory).
When I'm trying to get a corresponding `FileStream`, I get an exception that the specified folder can't be found.
That's my first problem.

My second problem is that after just viewing the download folder's content in Windows Explorer or after a device reset, myfile.ext won't be opened with my app. The file association seems to be gone.

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

> When I'm trying to get a corresponding FileStream, I get an exception that the specified folder can't be found.

If you get path form intent, it will start with `file:/` of `content:/` according to different file manager.

For example, you the path starts with `file:/`:

```
        if(Intent.DataString != null)
        {
            string path = Intent.DataString;            
            var fs = new FileStream(path.Remove(0, 6), FileMode.Open);
        }
```

> My second problem is that after just viewing the download folder's content in Windows Explorer or after a device reset, myfile.ext won't be opened with my app.

Is the Windows Explorer a file manager app? Some app may not display all available app to open the file, you could try to use another file manager.

Comment: I get the file's location via `Intent.GetParcelableExtra(Intent.ExtraStream)` and cast this to a `Uri`object. I thought that I get the right path with that object's `path` property. I will look have a look inside the `Intent.DataString` property.

When I view the phone's file system on my windows machine, and open the download directory, the file won't be opened with my app since then. I don't have to open the file. Just list the directory's files is enough.